Deeper understanding of Isaiah 50:10 “walks in darkness” phrasing?
Related Posting: Does Psalm 18:21 verse's use of term "Not wickedly" mean that he did Not intentionally,Not purposely or Not deliberately depart from God?

Isaiah 50 New American Standard Bible 1995
4 The Lord God has given Me the tongue of disciples, That I may know
how to sustain the weary one with a word. He awakens Me morning by
morning, He awakens My ear to listen as a disciple.
…..more scripture….more scripture….
…..more scripture….more scripture….
10 (a) Who is among you that fears the Lord,
(b) That obeys the voice of His servant,
( c )That walks in darkness and has no light?
(d) Let him trust in the name of the Lord and rely on his God.
…..more scripture….more scripture….


50:4-10 The Westminster Leningrad Codex
4 אֲדֹנָ֣י יְהוִֹ֗ה נָ֤תַן
לִי֙ לְשׁ֣וֹן לִמּוּדִ֔ים לָדַ֛עַת לָע֥וּת אֶת־יָעֵ֖ף דָּבָ֑ר יָעִ֣יר׀
בַּבֹּ֣קֶר בַּבֹּ֗קֶר יָעִ֥יר לִי֙ אֹ֔זֶן לִשְׁמֹ֖עַ כַּלִּמּוּדִֽים׃
.....more scripture .... more scripture.....
10 מִ֤י בָכֶם֙ יְרֵ֣א יְהוָ֔ה שֹׁמֵ֖עַ בְּק֣וֹל עַבְדּ֑וֹ אֲשֶׁ֣ר׀
הָלַ֣ךְ חֲשֵׁכִ֗ים וְאֵ֥ין נֹ֙גַהּ֙ ל֔וֹ יִבְטַח֙ בְּשֵׁ֣ם יְהוָ֔ה
וְיִשָּׁעֵ֖ן בֵּאלֹהָֽיו׃

Lets start with a brief contextual analysis of Isaiah 50.  Isaiah 50 begins with God complaining about Israel’s transgressions and iniquities
As we continue to read on, Isaiah 50:4 seems to be the Messiah, Jesus Christ, stating that He is given the role of being a disciple of God. As one reads Isaiah 50:7-9, The Messiah states that God stands with Him by vindicating & helping Him when He faces challenges.
Therefore, in Isaiah 50:10, The Messiah seems to challenge those who fear God to be in a state of reliance of God.
In Isaiah 50:10 ( c ), The Messiah strangely uses the phrase “walks in darkness” when He addresses the audience.
When The Messiah addresses the audience with the phrase “walks in darkness”, is He referring to audience members who do one of the following or some sort of combination of the following?  Also, please elaborate on your answer as well.

deliberate intentional willful inimical sinning/transgressing/”committing of iniquity” with an offensive offhanded attitude about consequences ( e.g. 2 Samuel 13:14 account of Amnon raping Tamar )

weakness-based driven sinning/transgressing/”committing of iniquity” with naivety about consequences ( e.g. 2 Samuel 11:4 account of David committing adultery with Bathsheba )

facing a precarious challenging situation ( e.g., 1 Samuel 23:15-17 account of David being afraid of King Saul’s intentions to harm David )




Isa 50:10, 11 - Who among you fears the LORD and obeys the voice of
his servant? Let him who walks in darkness and has no light trust in
the name of the LORD and rely on his God.  Behold, all you who kindle
a fire, who equip yourselves with burning torches! Walk by the light
of your fire, and by the torches that you have kindled! This you have
from my hand: you shall lie down in torment.

Note the deliberate contrast between walking by the light of the LORD and walking by the light of our own fire - the latter will lie down in torment.
Darkness is simply the lack of light (obviously).  Both words are used in the literal sense, and the spiritual sense where, in the latter case (as in Isa 50:10, 11):

"brightness"/"light" means to have spiritual enlightenment, eg, Prov 4:18, Isa 60:3, etc
"darkness" means an absence of spiritual enlightenment, and lack of divine guidance, eg, Ps 82:5, etc

These all remind us of the oft-repeated verses:

Ps 27:1 - The LORD is my light and my salvation—whom shall I fear? The LORD is the stronghold of my life—whom shall I dread?
Isa 9:2 - The people walking in darkness have seen a great light; on those living in the land of the shadow of death, a light has dawned. (Quoted by Matt 4:15, 16 about Jesus.)

In the NT this is explained further as a metaphor of Jesus, especially, in the Gospel of John -

John 1:4, 5 - In Him was life, and that life was the light of men. The light shines in the darkness, and the darkness has not overcome it.
John 1:9 - The true Light who gives light to every man was coming into the world.
John 8:12 - Once again, Jesus spoke to the people and said, “I am the light of the world. Whoever follows Me will never walk in the darkness, but will have the light of life.”
1 John 1:5 - And this is the message we have heard from Him and announce to you: God is light, and in Him there is no darkness at all.

Thus, Isa 50:10 uses a well-known Hebrew metaphor saying that people who walk in darkness do not have the spiritual light of the LORD and thus, walk in spiritual darkness.
The Pulpit commentary offers this:

Verses 10, 11. - AN ADDRESS OF JEHOVAH TO HIS CHURCH. Some suppose
that the Church of Hezekiah's reign is addressed; others the exiles
towards the close of the Captivity period. The first verse is an
exhortation, encouraging those who fear God, but have insufficient
light, to trust in him. The second threatens such as "kindle fire," or
cause strife, with retribution. Verse 10. - That obeyeth the voice of
his servant; that is, of "his servant" for the time being, whether
Isaiah, or Jeremiah, or "the Servant" κατ ἐξοχήν That walketh in
darkness. Not clearly seeing his way or knowing what his duty is, and
so inclined to despond and doubt. Every such person is bidden to put
aside his doubts, and trust wholly in the Name of the Lord, and stay
upon his God. Hence light will shine in upon him, and his doubts will
be resolved, and sufficient light will be granted him to direct his
paths. Isaiah 50:10

That is, people who walk in darkness deliberately reject the light of the leading of God and come to spiritual grief.

Correct me if I'm wrong, are you saying that Isaiah 50:10's phrase that states "walks in darkness" alludes to the 2nd and 3rd points (2) weakness-based driven sinning/transgressing/”committing of iniquity” with naivety about consequences ( e.g. 2 Samuel 11:4 account of David committing adultery with Bathsheba ) and (3) facing a precarious challenging situation ( e.g., 1 Samuel 23:15-17 account of David being afraid of King Saul’s intentions to harm David )?

@user1338998 - I have read your comment several times but cannot understand what you are saying.  However, I have interpreted the verse as I believe it should be understood which is not quite aligned with any of your points.

Isaiah chapter 50 addresses to the entire nation of Israel, rather than focus on defined individual. If it had to choose among the three options given by the OP, number three is close but still not definite.
The chapter begins with the Lord's declaration, that He has not abandoned Israel nor is He incapable of saving them, it is Israel who has forsaken the Lord and relied on their own strength (Isa 50:11 "walk in the light of your fires"). Isaiah, in contrast, remains steadfast in his faith, even when his neighbors mistreated him (Isa 50:6). The Lord empowers him to stand strong against his accusers (Isa 50:7-9).
Isaiah 50:10 addresses to individuals who maintain faith of the Lord. Even during moments of despair, when they feel as though they are walking in darkness, remains steadfast and trust in their Lord. It is because the Lord has not forsaken them; He is capable of saving them. This echoes the initial argument presented earlier in Isaiah 50:1-3.
The individuals who walks in darkness, are those who have lost hope for their future. This represents a period when the nation of Israel was in despair because they had forsaken their Lord. However, a remnant of people like Isaiah will find the light by steadfastly their faith in the Lord. On the other hand, those who rely on their own fires will find themselves consumed like torches set ablaze, lying down in torment (Isaiah 50:11).

First we should consider the opening of this section:

1     Thus says the Lord: Where is the bill of divorce
with which I dismissed your mother?

The fact of there being no bill of divorce means that God is still committed to bring Israel back, regardless of her sins. The entire nation comprises "those who walk in darkness yet trust in the name of the Lord." Israel has fallen, and now its people must look to the Lord, not their own wisdom, for salvation. This theme continues in chapter 51:

Listen to me, you who pursue justice,
who seek the Lord;
Look to the rock from which you were hewn,
to the quarry from which you were taken... the Lord shall comfort Zion,
shall comfort all her ruins; Her wilderness he shall make like Eden,
her wasteland like the garden of the Lord; Joy and gladness shall be found in her,
thanksgiving and the sound of song. (51:1-3)

"Those who walk in darkness" are the same people as "those who pursue justice." In both cases, they need to look to God for guidance. This understanding of the phrase works equally well whether one interprets these chapters as messianic (Christ speaking to the church) or "merely" prophetic (God speaking to His people Israel through Isaiah during the Exile).
